# Kotlin BottomSheetScaffold closes on recomposition

Tags: kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, compose-recomposition

I am using a bottomsheetscaffold in jetpack compose. Why does the sheet closes when a recomposition happens. Is this normal? How I can avoid it? I want to keep it alive when after recomposition.

**This is what I have on the normal page:**

```
items(count = getAllOrdersFromRestaurant.value.size) {
    if (getAllOrdersFromRestaurant.value[it]._id.toString() != orderId) {
        MeniuOfferItem(
            getAllOrdersFromRestaurant.value[it],
            totalPrice)
        }
   }
```

**On the sheet content** I have a button that when is clicked, modifies some content of getAllOrdersFromRestaurant. I dont understand why It auto-collapses when I click the button.

This is how I get getAllOrdersFromRestaurant:

```
val getAllOrdersFromRestaurant = remember {
            usersViewModel.getAllOrderFromRestaurant(
                restaurantId.toString()
            )
        }.observeAsState(emptyList())
```

Comment: Recomposition of what? You'll have to add more information about what's actually recomposing and add code sample of your composables before anyone can tell you what's happening.

Comment: can you add the code ?

Comment: Done, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add **remember** to the `bottoShetState`:

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
            bottomSheetState = remember { BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed) }
        )
```